# How to pass ifdef defines to a .f file

Tags: compilation, verilog, conditional-compilation

Hi is there any way to add `ifdef in .f files. I have a .f file which includes hierarchial compilation.

```
`ifdef ASIC

rtl/a.v

`else
rtl/b.v
endif
```

this is my intention if ASIC is passed as define a.v needs to compile. else b.v. Does the above code works without adding any extra things?

Comment: no, there is no way provided by the verilog tools. you can write a script for it. However i strongly recommend to avoid this methodology since eventually it will create maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My aim is that I need to pass the file list during compilation so as  per the defines passing along with compile option from my main perl script the files need to compile from the file list(the file also  i will add as -f filelist.f with  my compile options). I am planning to pass the options from perl script to the file list. Do you have suggestion or any better way to do this?

Comment: you can generate your file lists in the perl script.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any tool that does this on the command line. Either create the .f file dynamically as part of your build process, or use a Verilog file to do this instead.

```
`ifdef ASIC

`include "rtl/a.v"

`else
`include "rtl/b.v"
`endif
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply dave_59. So do you mean the code snippet you shared i can made it as a verilog or systemverilog file and use it? Also  how to create a .f file dynamically as a part of build process? My aim is that I need to pass the file list during compilation so as  per the defines passing along with compile option the files need to compile from the file list. I am planning to pass the options from perl script to the file list. Do you have suggestion or any better way to do this?

Comment: Yes, the code snippet should be made into a Verilog file. This assumes the only thing you had in inside file.f were lists of other files and no other command line switches. If so you'll have to keep those in a separate .f file. If you are building your simulation scripts from a perl script, there's no reason you can't create a file.f from perl as well.

Comment: This assumes the only thing you had in inside file.f were lists of other files and no other command line switches. If so you'll have to keep those in a separate .f file. If you are building your simulation scripts from a perl script, there's no reason you can't create a file.f from perl as well. I didnt get what yo meant by these two lines can you please elaborate?

Answer (score -1):

You can only handle ifdefs in verilog.  So include a new file, say asic_defines.vh
`include asic_defines.vh

And in asic_defines.vh, you can have the ifdef:

`ifdef ASIC` include rtl/a.v
`else` include rtb/b.v
`endif

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).